# How to insert xml response in salesforce object

Tags: apex, apexrest, xmlparsing

I want to insert XML Response (Quantity,InStock) into salesforce Custom object(Test__c) in custom fields (Quantity__c and Instock__c) based on SellerSKU.see below XML Response. Please Help me how to do xml parsing into apex.

```
<SupplyResult>
 <MarketId>xxxxxxxx</MarketId>
 <SupplyList>
    <member>
        <Quantity>9</Quantity>
        <InStock>5</InStock>
        <SellerSKU>Test- 1111</SellerSKU>
    </member>
  </SupplyList>
  </SupplyResult>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? Have you hit any specific roadblocks? Right now this question reads like you haven't bothered to search. See: [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)

Comment: Thanks Adrian , i did integration salsforce to AmazonMWS, i got above response,but i want save that elements values in salesforce,i tried but am strucked in xml parsing.

Comment: A [quick search](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bxml%5d%20parse) on the [xml tag](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/xml/info), sorted by votes, provides good learning material, such as [Difficulty Parsing XML](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/difficulty-parsing-xml)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find everything you need to accomplish the task at hand in the `Apex Developer Guide` documentation: **[Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)**. You can use the **`Dom.Document` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document)** to do the heavy lifting. This would also be a good time to define some *inner classes* to do your data processing. Something like:

```
public class SupplyResult
{
    final String marketId;
    final List<SupplyMember> members;
    public SupplyResult(String xml)
    {
        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(xml);

        //further processing
    }
}
public class SupplyMember
{
    final Integer quantity, inStock;
    final String sellerSKU;
    public Supply(Dom.XmlNode node)
    {
        quantity = Integer.valueOf(node.getChildElement('Quantity', null).getText());
        // etc
    }
}
```

It will be a better learning experience if you fill in the gaps above instead of having me provide every step. It should be straightforward. I only omitted eight lines of code (though you could do it with fewer if you were so inclined).